# Selenium Safari WebDriver Not Signing in

Tags: selenium, groovy, safari, automation, geb

So a simple test is working completely fine using my automations chrome and firefox webdrivers. Upon attempting to add and configure safari into the mix it's simply not advancing to the next screen once sign-in is pressed.

The automation code and page elements are the same for all 3 browsers and for some reason only safari does not proceed past sign-in. Almost like the driver isn't being "seen" correctly. The username and password fields are being populated and the sign-in button is clearly being clicked yet its not responding for some reason.

The test: 
1. Load my companies website.
2. Enter the username and password
3. Click sign-in which brings the user to the dashboard.

I'm utilizing and customized the gradle project found here: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle

My configurations which relate to me adding safari:

GebConfig.groovy:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver

environments {

//Use this environment to run specs locally using Chrome.
chrome {
    driver = { /*def driverInstance = new ChromeDriver()
        driverInstance.manage().window().maximize()
        driverInstance*/ //old

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized")

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>()
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false)
        prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false)
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
    }
}

//Use this environment to run specs on Safari.
safari {
    driver = {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().safari()
        capabilities.setCapability("cleanSession", true)
        def driverInstance = new SafariDriver(capabilities)
        //driverInstance.manage().deleteAllCookies() //not working
        driverInstance

        //new SafariDriver() //plain
    }
}

//Use this environment to run test locally using Firefox.
firefox {
    driver = {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox()
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true)
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox")
        new FirefoxDriver(capabilities)
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
ext {
// The drivers we want to use
drivers = ["firefox", "chrome", "phantomJs", "safari"]
ext {
    groovyVersion = '2.4.5'
    gebVersion = '1.0'
    seleniumVersion = '3.4'
    chromeDriverVersion = '2.28'
    firefoxDriverVersion = '0.16.1'
    safariDriverVersion = '2.48.0'
    phantomJsVersion = '1.9.7'
}
}

dependencies {
testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:$seleniumVersion"

chromeTest {
dependsOn unzipChromeDriver
def chromedriverFilename = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "chromedriver.exe" : "chromedriver"
systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", new File(unzipChromeDriver.outputs.files.singleFile, chromedriverFilename).absolutePath
}

phantomJsTest {
dependsOn unzipPhantomJs
def phantomJsFilename = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "phantomjs.exe" : "bin/phantomjs"
systemProperty "phantomjs.binary.path", new File(unzipPhantomJs.outputs.files.singleFile, phantomJsFilename).absolutePath
}

firefoxTest {
dependsOn unzipFirefoxDriver
systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", new File(unzipFirefoxDriver.outputs.files.singleFile, "geckodriver").absolutePath
}

safariTest {
systemProperty "webdriver.safari.driver", "~/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari"
}

test {
dependsOn drivers.collect { tasks["${it}Test"] }
enabled = false
}
```

My safari version: 10.1
and I have the webdriver extension installed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGbtu.png

Since I know the elements and automation code isn't the issue I won't include them. I'm wondering if anyone notices something wrong with how I have the safariTest task configured or safari environment itself. Keep in mind the safari webdriver is behaving correctly enough to load the page, input the username/password and click sign-in but nothing else. My confusion with the safari webdriver is how its built in versus chrome/firefox where I follow the same geb project stucture of downloading, unzipping and loading those drivers that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you completely sure that the button is being clicked? While I don't have any experience using Safari with Selenium, I do know that the various webdrivers aren't consistent with where they click elements. E.g. Chrome will click the very middle of an element while PhantomJS will click the top left. It's possible that it may be very slightly missing the button if it's rounded or there's overlap with another element. What I've done in similar situations is used ActionChains (to move with an offset) or executed javascript.

Comment: Yes. A little animation even occurs once the click happens which is clearly visible. Odder still if I kill the automation and manually click on it without closing the safari instance, it still doesn't sign-in or advance the webpage. Obviously if I open Safari manually it signs in fine.